# How do I calculate surface area given a three dimensional coordinates of a face?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

I have three dimensional coordinates of a face, how do I calculate surface area?

Comment: What kind of face do you mean?

Comment: It can be any shape, but in the simpler case I can assume it to be a rectangle face.

Comment: Likely you have faces of a polyhedron in mind (it's worth stating this explicitly).  One difficulty is that if the coordinates are not represented exactly, a face with more than three vertices may fail to lie exactly in a plane, due to rounding errors.

Answer (score 1):

In general for a parametized face $\vec F(u,v)$ the area is the integral
$$A=\int \left|\frac{\text d\vec F(u,v)}{\text du}\times\frac{\text d\vec F(u,v)}{\text dv}\right|\text du \text dv$$